# Errors in created application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I have installed Eclipse. When I create new Android application, there are lots of errors in  style.xml and in main class:

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2014-12-29 12:09:05 - testing] D:\android\testing\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2014-12-29 12:09:05 - testing] 
[2014-12-29 12:09:05 - testing] D:\android\testing\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2014-12-29 12:09:05 - testing] 
[2014-12-29 12:09:05 - testing] D:\android\testing\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2014-12-29 12:09:05 - testing] 
[2014-12-29 12:09:43 - appcompat_v7] Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.
[2014-12-29 12:09:46 - Asdfghjk] D:\android\Asdfghjk\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2014-12-29 12:09:46 - Asdfghjk] 
[2014-12-29 12:09:46 - Asdfghjk] D:\android\Asdfghjk\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2014-12-29 12:09:46 - Asdfghjk] 
[2014-12-29 12:09:46 - Asdfghjk] D:\android\Asdfghjk\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2014-12-29 12:09:46 - Asdfghjk] 
[2014-12-29 12:09:49 - Asdfghjk] D:\android\Asdfghjk\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2014-12-29 12:09:49 - Asdfghjk] 
[2014-12-29 12:09:49 - Asdfghjk] D:\android\Asdfghjk\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2014-12-29 12:09:49 - Asdfghjk] 
[2014-12-29 12:09:49 - Asdfghjk] D:\android\Asdfghjk\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2014-12-29 12:09:49 - Asdfghjk]
```

Comment: please did you atleast search why? because alot  of people have had your problems and others solved 'em for them on stackoverflow, so please google ayt..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your build target is set to the correct API Level.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Answer (score 0):

Create Application without Default activity.It will solve your problem